почему возникает Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'? не видит установленные модули
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python_project\1001\1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

при этом модуль установлен
pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
PyAutoGUI          0.9.54

сделано в виртуальном окружении
(venv_1001) PS D:\Python_project\1001> python --version
Python 3.12.2

сюда же и ставил такой командой
pip install pyautogui


возможные дубликаты

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Ошибка pip3 install pyautogui: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'"

установил xlib, сейчас и на него ругается, получается не видит установленные модули

Значит, запускаете питон не из того окружения, в которое поставили библиотеки.

подскажите пжл как это проверить? в pycharm внизу справа стоит Curent interpretator 3.12

Ну вот там и нужно выбрать "(venv_1001)", если вы в это окружение библиотеки ставили.

выше указывал
(venv_1001) PS D:\Python_project\1001> python --version
Python 3.12.2

сюда же и ставил

(venv_1001) PS D:\Python_project\1001> pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
PyAutoGUI          0.9.54

Это всё понятно, в PyCharm нужно выбрать это окружение.

не понимаю где его выбирать, учитывая что везде 3.12
но при - py -3.12 -m pip install pyautogui вроде как все стало на свои места, интересно другое куда же оно тогда установило предыдущую

Окружение не определяется одной только версией питона. Вы можете иметь сколько угодно окружений с одной и той же версией питона, но разным составом установленных библиотек. Вы пробовали нажимать то поле где написано "Current interpretator 3.12"?

да нажимал, везде в настройках которые попадались на глаза стоит 3.12, потому и не понимаю почему не работало

Я могу повторить. Выбор питона 3.12 не гарантирует вам, что вы выбрали именно то окружение, куда вы ставили библиотеки. У вас может быть несколько (да сколько угодно) окружений с питоном 3.12 и при этом разным составом библиотек.
